# Resorting a list in Angularjs breaks ng-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I wrote a jquery plugin that allows users to use either touch or mouse ([kind of like this](https://github.com/heyman/jquery-draggable-touch/blob/master/jquery.draggableTouch.js)) to resort a ul. The plugin works fine for updating the DOM but I'm not sure how to tell Angular to "update" the model binding. Specifically, the ng-click i have in the li doesn't fire after an li is moved. I'd also like to update the $index and tell the server what the new order is. Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<ul class="unstyled" ng-sortable>
    <li ng-repeat="item in list.Items">
        {{item.QuantityType.Name}} {{item.Name}} {{index}}
        <button class="close" ng-click="deleteItem($index)" aria-hidden="true">&times</button></li></ul>
```

Directive:

```
.directive('ngSortable',  function () {
        return {
            link: function (scope, element) {
                angular.element(element).draggableTouch({ onSortEndCallback: function () { scope.finishedSorting(); } });
            }
        };
    })
```

EDIT: added code for more context.

Comment: Why not use the built in [orderBy](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:orderBy)?

Comment: I am, but I want the user to be able to change the order.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `ng-click="deleteItem($index)"` is not working

I would suggest you to pass `item` instead of `$index` so change your code as

```
 ng-click="deleteItem(item)"
```

You can use `indexOf` function to find elements index in the array

```
 scope.list.Items.indexOf(item)
```

Comment: The ng-click doesn't fire. For example, ng-click="alert('hi')" doesn't work after the item has been resorted.

Answer (score 0):

Call the controller in your plugin after a click or touch. You can access the scope from outside your controller angular.element(domElement).scope() to get the current scope for the element.
Then update a $scope.sort (to send to server) and $index with the data in the plugin.

Comment: Sorry, did not see the edit in time. Thought you ment a plugin not in angular, but,... It is a directive.